# How to create a custom html with shortcode WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a custom payment for WordPress, is a simple code but I need to hide the code, I thought about creating a shortcode [custom_shorcode].

When I put the shortcode i need to display a custom html with php.

Comment: You will need to create a plug-in. Follow the example [here](https://www.inkthemes.com/learn-how-to-create-shortcodes-in-wordpress-plugin-with-examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the functions.php or a simple Plugin.
To create it in the functions.php of your child-theme, do it like this:

```
add_shortcode('your-shortcode', 'yourFunction');
function yourFunction(){
   //do your stuff
}
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: if i need convert this code to plugin only need create a folder in "/wp-content/plugins" but what is the name of the php document? index.php or myfunction.php? @tobias

Comment: yes, create a folder in /wp-content/plugins/ and name the file as you like (with.php)

Comment: I think it is necessary to add the plugin header where the plugin name data, creator, version, etc... A user left the necessary information in this post.

Comment: yes of course...see the documentation (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/)